# Is there a better way of writing these if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Essentially, these if statements rapidly change the colour of a cv2 line when an object passes over it problem is that there is 4 lines and I want to keep the lines red before and after the color changes to green.

This not only looks terrible but is probably not efficent

```
if counter is 1:
    cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos1, 0), (line_pos1, height), line_col_green, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos2, 0), (line_pos2, height), line_col_red, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos4), (width, line_pos4), line_col_red, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos5), (width, line_pos5), line_col_red, line_size)
    lct1 += 1
if counter is 2:
    cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos1, 0), (line_pos1, height), line_col_red, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos2, 0), (line_pos2, height), line_col_green, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos4), (width, line_pos4), line_col_red, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos5), (width, line_pos5), line_col_red, line_size)
    lct2 += 1
if counter is 3:
    cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos1, 0), (line_pos1, height), line_col_red, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos2, 0), (line_pos2, height), line_col_red, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos4), (width, line_pos4), line_col_green, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos5), (width, line_pos5), line_col_red, line_size)
    lct3 += 1
if counter is 4:
    cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos1, 0), (line_pos1, height), line_col_red, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos2, 0), (line_pos2, height), line_col_red, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos4), (width, line_pos4), line_col_red, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos5), (width, line_pos5), line_col_green, line_size)
    lct4 += 1
if counter is 0:
    cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos1, 0), (line_pos1, height), line_col_red, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos2, 0), (line_pos2, height), line_col_red, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos4), (width, line_pos4), line_col_red, line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos5), (width, line_pos5), line_col_red, line_size)
```

Comment: why not using if elif ?

Comment: If while writing the code, you had to copy paste some lines and make minor tweaks, then you should immediately have alarm bells ringing in your head. You're absolutely right, there should be a better way. (Usually in the form of making functions). The only trouble is, visually this is very hard to figure out what's different exactly for us.

Comment: Also, do not use `is` to check for equality of integers, use `counter == 4` and so on. You are not getting errors because of small int cache, which is an implementation detail and should not be relied on. tl;dr, use `==` and avoid `is` for ints.

Comment: The difference is the color for each line changes to green and the rest stay red as well as a different counter increases.  `lct1`, `lct2` etc are the counters that change

Comment: as @mik1904 said, you can use `elif` instead of `if` from the second `if`, which will improve efficiency because once python knows one case is true, it won't check the others

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding on my comment.
Here is something something quick to illustrate how you could use a function for this. This may not be the only way to do it, and there may be something better, but you can start with something like this.

```
def set_line_colour(counter):
    line_colours = [line_col_red] * 4 #makes a list of 4 "Reds"
    if counter != 0: #or more simply, if counter: (because 0 is "falsey")
        line_colours[counter - 1] = line_col_green #sets one of the "Reds" to green instead.
    cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos1, 0), (line_pos1, height), line_colours[0], line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos2, 0), (line_pos2, height), line_colours[1], line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos4), (width, line_pos4), line_colours[2], line_size)
    cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos5), (width, line_pos5), line_colours[3], line_size)
```

General rule of thumb that may help you: If you ever find yourself copy pasting lines while writing code, stop and think whether you could turn it into a function perhaps.

Also, sidenote: Use `==` for comparison with ints, not `is`.

---

Disclaimer: This code is not tested, please verify and make changes if necessary before use.

Comment: Also I just placed the lct variables in a list and used it like so `lst[counter-1] += 1`

Comment: Also this straight up reduced my run times on a 50sec video by 3 seconds 113-114 sec before and now its 109-110 sec (5 runs on the video to check times were reasonably reliable)

Answer (score 3):

Two main things :

- Use `elif` instead of multiple `if` if they are exclusive.
- If some code is repeated, use a function to respect the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle.

You could also (but not necessary) use a 'custom' [switch-case in python](https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html)

Answer (score 2):

What about using a dict (or list)?

```
colors = {1: (line_col_green, line_col_red, line_col_red, line_col_red),
         2: (line_col_red, line_col_green, line_col_red, line_col_red),
         ... }

c1, c2, c3, c4 = colors[counter]
cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos1, 0), (line_pos1, height), c1, line_size)
cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos2, 0), (line_pos2, height), c2, line_size)
cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos4), (width, line_pos4), c3, line_size)
cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos5), (width, line_pos5), c4, line_size)
```

And a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for the `lct` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a dictionary, I would code like the following, keeping your variables intact. Assuming that line is a function we use

```
col={'Line1':[line_col_red,line_col_green,line_col_red,line_col_red,line_col_red],'Line2':[line_col_red,line_col_red,line_col_green,line_col_red,line_col_red],'Line3':[line_col_red,line_col_red,line_col_red,line_col_green,line_col_red],'Line4':[line_col_red,line_col_red,line_col_red,line_col_red,line_col_green]}

cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos1, 0), (line_pos1, height), col['Line1'][counter], line_size)
cv2.line(input_frame, (line_pos2, 0), (line_pos2, height), col['Line2'][counter], line_size)
cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos4), (width, line_pos4), col['Line3'][counter], line_size)
cv2.line(input_frame, (0, line_pos5), (width, line_pos5), col['Line4'][counter], line_size)
if counter is 1:
    lct1 += 1
elif counter is 2:
    lct2 += 1
elif counter is 3:
    lct3 += 1
elif counter is 4:
    lct4 += 1
```